# MySql Insert into.....(error)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting an insert error when I'm trying to insert data from a form to my database. the error is as follows :

> Error: INSERT INTO users (firstname) VALUES ('a')

This is the code:

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
     $registerfirstname = $_POST['firstname'];
     $query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname) VALUES ('$registerfirstname')";

     if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
        echo "New user created";
    }else{
        echo "Error: " .$query. "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't post the error, you posted only the query. give us the output of `mysqli_error($conn)`, not just `$query`

Comment: I get no error when i run through phpMyAdmin, but i get this error 'Error: INSERT INTO users (firstname) VALUES ('a') '  when i run the .php file

Comment: @KieranDavidCarratt That's the error *you* made, what about the one from `mysqli_error($conn)` (if any)? The query looks fine, so I'm guessing that the connection is bad, could you post that code?

Comment: Database is connected ok. $registerfirstname is connected to a register form and when is 'submited' the $registerfirstname is inserting into my users

Comment: Does the user have permissions to insert into the database? Have you checked if [`error_reporting(-1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) give anything?

Comment: I have simplified it down so im only working with a 'name' field and submit button. 'error_reporting(-1);' gives no error

Answer (score 0):

You are making a little mistake here. You have to pass the variable data through the [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) through first. An example would be ,

`$registerfirstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($registerfirstname);`

And after that you can use it in sql like that. This way it is more sanitized. I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Yep he may be right. If you don't escape the code and if you have an apostrophe in the string, it will fail to succeed

Comment: One note though, don't suggest `mysql_` when OP is using `mysqli_`. They don't mix. Secondly, filtering input like that *might not* be (but as the comment above suggest, *could* be) the issue of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the edit , @Qirel . I didn't notice the `mysqli` there . A big thanks .

Comment: I'm still getting the same error even when i pass my data through mysqli_real_escape_string(). Could there be another problem i have overlooked ? I know the database i connected ok as in another query I can execute a check query(and everything is ok)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use Mysql Workbenck to prepare sql statements. If, The statements properly work on workbench.Paste into the php script.

On php side, you should use mysql_real_escape_string() function before set your variable.

Like;

```
 $registerfirstname =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
```

Comment: OP is using mysqli, so should the answer.

Comment: Mysqli version is ;

$registerfirstname  = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);

Comment: OP is using procedural, not object `mysqli_`, and please update your answer - don't write it as a comment :-)

Comment: The user's hosting provider may not allow remote connection through applications such as MySQL Workbench, or they might prefer using phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Create connection
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');
// Check connection
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
} 

$firstname = "John";
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($firstname);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname) VALUES ('$firstname')";

if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New user created";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connection->error;
}
// Close connection
$connection->close();
```

It should work, but if it doesn't just give us what errors are shown.

Comment: error is still the same : 'Error: INSERT INTO users (firstname) VALUES ('')'

Comment: Try the updated code again, I make a mistake in the connection check.

Comment: ah ok im getting somewhere :), im now getting the following error: ` Connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. `

Comment: Are you testing on your local host or a hosting provider's service? Make sure you have also properly filled the username, password and dbname with your connection details.